# How to show local HTML file in App Inventor

Tags: html, app-inventor

How can I show a locally hosted HTML page in App Inventor WITHOUT using WebViewer?

Since file select doesn't work in WebView I created an html file which uploads sends data to an external source. So I would like to load the HTML page in App Inventor without WebView.

If it's not possible how can I create an HTML form in App Inventor (No Webview)?

Answer (score 1):

To view a HTML page in App Inventor, generally there are 2 possibilities

1. to use the `webviewer` component
2. to use the `activity starter` to open an external browser, see also [Using the Activity Starter](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/activitystarter.html)

for 2. the HTML page must be moved to sdcard or available in the internet somewhere, because an external app can't access the assets of your App Inventor app.

Alternatively use the `web` component to upload data to somewhere, for example

- [How to use the PostFile block in App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php) or
- [App Inventor - Google Drive Interface](https://puravidaapps.com/drive.php).